# How to Add New Custom record Item in netsuite using webservices?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, k2, suitetalk

I have created a new custom record called "XYZ" and i created all the fields into it.
Now i can add new entry on that Custom record using GUI but how do i do similar action using webservices.

What methods needs to be summoned to add new item in custom record type and how do we do it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Below is the sample C# code to add custom record using SuiteTalk (webservices) -

```
CustomRecord customRecord = new CustomRecord();

RecordRef recordType = new RecordRef();
recordType.internalId = "14"; // // Record Type's internal ID (Setup > Customization > Record Types > Basic Record Type (Internal ID=14)
recordType.type = RecordType.customRecord;
recordType.typeSpecified = true;

customRecord.recType = recordType;
customRecord.internalId = "7"; // internal id of the custom record you want to update

StringCustomFieldRef stringCustomFieldRef = new StringCustomFieldRef();
stringCustomFieldRef.scriptId = "custrecord_pe_pbmastertrackno";
stringCustomFieldRef.value = txtMasterTrackno.Text.Trim();

CustomFieldRef[] customFieldRef = new CustomFieldRef[1];
customFieldRef[0] = stringCustomFieldRef;

customRecord.customFieldList = customFieldRef;

_service = new NetSuiteService();

setPassport(); // Set the Passport information for authentication
WriteResponse writeResponse = _service.add(customRecord);
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the script, i also have a required field on the record type "XYZ" called "xyz date" how do i populate that. Also on your script why are we passing internal id twice. What does first internal id signify and what does second one signify?

Comment: As provided in code comments, second internal id is required if you wants to update existing record. For date field, you can create custom date field object similar to provided in sample script for string field.

Comment: What if we want to add new record with all its fields populated. Also i have Include Name field checked (which is a required field) in the record type i am using. How do i populate that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new restlet with following code and call restlet using post method with recordtype and field values

```
function createNewRecord(datain){

var recType = datain.recordtype;
var field1 = datain.field1;
var field2 = datain.field2;
var field3 = datain.field3;

var record = nlapiCreateRecord(recType);
record.setFieldValue('custrecord_field1', field1);
record.setFieldValue('custrecord_field2', field2);
record.setFieldValue('custrecord_field3', field3);
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);

var dd = JSON.stringify(id);
return dd;
}
```

Restlet Call

```
var account = 'XXXXXXX';
var email = 'XXXX@domain.com';
var signature = 'XXXXXXXX';
var role = '3';

var recordtype = 'XYZ';
var custrecord_field1 = 'value1';
var custrecord_field2 = 'value2';
var custrecord_field3 = 'value3';

var newRec = {"recordtype": recordtype, "field1":custrecord_field1, "field2":custrecord_field2, "field3":custrecord_field3}
var url = 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=231&deploy=1';
var params = {
contentType: 'application/json',
headers:{Authorization: 'NLAuth nlauth_account='+account+', nlauth_email='+email+', nlauth_signature='+signature+', nlauth_role='+role},
method: 'POST',
muteHttpExceptions: true,
payload: JSON.stringify(newRec)
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var resdata = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(resdata);
```